# jQuery change text in link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question for jQuery...

I have a table with a link like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="views-field">
      <a href="ciao">201105</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I would change the link's text from 201105 to 2011-05

(simple add a "-" after the first 4 characters)

I tried substring but don't work... Help me!!

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? It would make pointing out the error easier.

Comment: What have you tried? We're happy to help but would rather not do your homework :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will translate all td.views-field links:

```
$('td.views-field a').each(function () {
  var oldText = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(oldText.substr(0,4) + '-' + oldText.substr(4));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, that should work fine.

```
var replaceElement = $("td.views-field a").first();
var oldDate = replaceElement.text();

var newDate = oldDate.substring(0, 4) + "-" + oldDate.substring(4,6);
replaceElement.text(newDate);
```

Comment: Why you are alerting variable instead of replace it curious me

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").text($("a").text().substring(0,4)+"-"+$("a").text().substring(4,6) );
```

Comment: In my opinion this is a piece of bad readable and maintainable code.

Comment: it do what it supposed to do, its just an example